# How to modify .line numbers in smali file?

Tags: apk, smali, apktool

I have used apktool to decompile an apk to its smali source.
In all smali files there are .lineXYZ codes. They are random 
i.e 
.line 2

and somewhere next it would be like .line 33

so i am unable to get their sequence. I have created a line number modification tool which renames line number and applied to smli files. But apktool did not compile it again and exited without telling me anything.
then i created a tool to detect highest line number in the project and added my code to decompiled code. Still apk did exist without saying anything.

I know there is a file known as apktool.yml but i do not know if there is any problem in that.

Any help is appreciated and i am waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`.line` markers are just for debugging and show up in stacktraces. You don't need to modify them when you're adding code.